# Name this geometric point?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Is there a formal name for the point which is the reflection of the incenter about the circumcenter of a triangle?

Comment: Try computing its trilinear or barycentric coordinates, then look the result up in [the encyclopedia of triangle centers](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/etc.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reflection of the incenter about the circumcenter is the *Bevan point* of the triangle. Quoting from the [mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BevanPoint.html) page:

> The Bevan point $V$ of a triangle $\triangle ABC$ is the circumcenter of the [excentral triangle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExcentralTriangle.html) $\triangle J_AJ_BJ_C$. It is named in honor of Benjamin Bevan, a relatively unknown Englishman [who] proposed the problem of proving that the circumcenter $O$ was the midpoint of the incenter $I$ and the circumcenter of the excentral triangle and that the circumradius of the excentral triangle was $2R$ (Bevan 1806), a problem solved by John Butterworth (1806).